# 1) Loop through array of sheet/file IDs 2) Use DriveApp to getLastUpdated for each file 3) setValues in adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets, setvalue, getfiles, getvalue

The log spits out the information that I want (a timestamp of when the file was last updated), but when trying to setValues() in the adjacent column, I get "Exception: The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."

More specifically...

var sheetID is a list of spreadsheet IDs from various sources

var pasteRange is the array in which I want to paste in the date/time that the sheet was last updated.

```
function getLastModified() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getTab = ss.getSheetByName("Tab1");
  var sheetID = getTab.getRange("L2:L101").getValues();
  var pasteRange = getTab.getRange("K2:K101");

  for (i=0;i<sheetID.length;i++){
     if(sheetID[i] == ""){

     } else {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetID[i]);
      var date = file.getLastUpdated();

//      
pasteRange.setValues(date);
      
//the log works
Logger.log(date)
     }
     }

  }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`setValues()` requires a 2D array and you are passing one value. You can try this code that loops through all rows, accumulates values in `dates` array and then records all of them at once. As a benefit, it will be much faster.

```js
function getLastModified() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getTab = ss.getSheetByName("Tab1");
  var sheetID = getTab.getRange("L2:L101").getValues();
  var pasteRange = getTab.getRange("K2:K101");
  const dates = [];

  for (i = 0; i < sheetID.length; i++) {
    if (!sheetID[i]) {
      dates.push([null]);
      continue;
    }
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetID[i]);
    const date = file.getLastUpdated();
    dates.push([date]);

    //the log works
    Logger.log(date);
  }
  pasteRange.setValues(dates);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I forgot to mentioned that the array of IDs

var sheetID = getTab.getRange("L2:L101").getValues();

has blank cells as well.  What is the protocol to skip those cells, so that the resulting date stays in the same row as the IDs?

Comment: @MarStac The standard way is to check whether the value evaluates to false with `if (!sheetID[i]) continue`.  There can be false positives in some cases (for example, if the cell contains a `0`), but in your case it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Apologies for bothering again, but I'm having difficulty applying this false evaluation into my specific code.  Would you be able to amend the code with your suggestion? I'm struggling to understand the logic.

Comment: @MarStac Sure.  I have updated the code.  Now if the cell is `sheetID[i]` is empty it adds an empty row to `dates` and continues to the next row. Without sample data I cannot properly test it, let me know if there are any issues, please.

Comment: I'm getting an error message on the line with "var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetID[i]);"

"Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp."

FYI...I was able to make a workaround using your initial code by making a filtered array with no spaces on another tab, but honestly...it hurts my soul and it feels like I just lost the big game.

Comment: @MarStac Could you share the spreadsheet with sample data that you are using, please?